# How to get full url from <a> tag using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, url, redirect, undefined

I have a notification `div`. When someone clicks one of the links, the number of notification will be changed and after that the user will be redirected to the link that he clicked. Here is the php script inside the `div`.

```
<?php
 while($row = stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
 {
 echo "<p><a href='http://example.com/blog/index.php?t_id=".$t_id."&c_id=".$c_id."'>".$title."</a></p>";
 }
?>
```

I am using the following Jquery inside the `div`:

```
<script>
 $('p').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "http://www.example.com/change_notification.php"
 })
 .done(function( msg ) {

 $("#changed_notification_value").text( msg );
 var n_url = $('a', this).attr('href');
 window.location.href = n_url;

 });
});
</script>
```

Number of the notification changes successfully but when trying to redirect, the value of `n_url` shows undefined.

Comment: Have you tried that the jQuery selector is correct?

Comment: @Anzeo `the value of n_url shows undefined`

Comment: @zzlalani I know, I'm asking whether the `$('a', this)` returns anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have a problem of scope when using `this`. You can do something like this to fix the problem. Get the `n_url` before making the ajax request.

```
$('p').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var n_url = $('a', this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.com/change_notification.php"
    }).done(function (msg) {

        $("#changed_notification_value").text(msg);
        window.location.href = n_url;
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh sorry about that :-)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var n_url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `$('a', this)`. It's just a shorthand for `.find()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   var n_url = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
     window.location.href = n_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` does not work like it does in other languages. When not inside a function (think global space) `this` refers to the `Window` object of the current browser. By default, new functions are created as children of `Window`.

For example;

```
function foo() {
    return this;
}
```

Is actually the same as `Window.foo = function() { return this; }` (unless browser is in strict mode).

So when you call `foo()` the following is true.

```
foo() === window;   // True, because foo() returns this which is window.
```

Since by default `this` refers to the object the function is bound to. You can change the default value of `this` by binding the function to a different object.

```
var o = {
    x: 99,
    foo: function() {
        return this.x;
    }
};

console.log(o.foo());   // will output 99
```

It doesn't matter when you bind the function to an object. As in this example.

```
var a = {
    x: 99
};

var b = {
    x: 77
};

function foo() {
    return this.x;
}

a.f = foo;
b.f = foo;

console.log(a.f());   // will output 99
console.log(b.f());   // will output 77
```

In the above example the function `foo` is the same, but `this` changes depending on which bound object reference was used to call it.

So what is going on with DOM events?

The function is bound to the DOM element, and that's a Javascript object. So `this` refers to the object that triggers the event. *Even* if the same function is bound to multiple elements. `this` always refers to the one that triggered the function.

So now back your source code and problem. Your using `this` inside the `.done(function(msg){....})` function. jQuery has bound the `ajax` object to the function so that `this` refers to that object.

You can change what `this` refers too by using the `bind()` function. `bind` lets you change what object is bound to the function so that `this` refers to that object instead.

```
$('p').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.com/change_notification.php"
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $("#changed_notification_value").text( msg );
        var n_url = $('a', this).attr('href');
        window.location.href = n_url;
    }.bind(this));
});
```

Above, I didn't change your source code but just added `.bind(this)` to the end of your `function(msg){...}.bind(this)`.  The object `this` refers to outside the function is the DOM element that triggered the event, and by binding it to your callback function for `done` your source code should now work.